# Fusion Charts not rendering

Tags: javascript, python, flask, fusioncharts

Here i am trying to test FusionCharts with Flask and i am not able to get it working while it works when its used just as plain HTML and javascript with no Python code.

**layout.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flask Fusion</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/fusion.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../static/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--

       var myChart = new FusionCharts( "../static/Column3D.swf",
      "myChartId", "400", "300", "0" );
      myChart.setXMLUrl("data.xml");
      myChart.render("chartContainer");

    // -->
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

**Directory Structure**

[image]

I have found that `data.xml` file returns `404` by seeing the logs from the console which are like this

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jan/2014 13:25:35] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jan/2014 13:25:35] "GET /static/fusion.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jan/2014 13:25:35] "GET /static/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jan/2014 13:25:35] "GET /data.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jan/2014 13:25:35] "GET /static/Column3D.swf HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jan/2014 13:25:35] "GET /data.xml?FCTime=261 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

But the path to `data.xml` is perfectly correct. I dont know why its not rendering. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data.xml` is not retrieved and put in the chart at flask-template-rendering time. When the client, that have loaded the fusion.js lib, call the chart initialization, a request is made to retrieve the resource and so it should be accessible from the client side.

`data.xml` is inaccessible (hence 404) from the client side (since it's in the `template/` folder) and on top of that the path is wrong as you can see here:

```
...
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jan/2014 13:25:35] "GET /data.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Jan/2014 13:25:35] "GET /static/Column3D.swf HTTP/1.1" 304 -
...
```

`/static/Column3D.swf` is fetched using `http://whateveryour.domain/static/Column3D.swf`
whereas `/data.xml` is fetched using `http://whateveryour.domain/data.xml` which don't exists.

Try to put your `data.xml` in the static folder (after all that's a static resource more than it is a template) and to access it the same way you did with `Column3D.swf`and it should work just fine.